# Error using Page Adaptererror

Tags: android

```
package com.example.kiran.slidetabs;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;



public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    int tabCount;
    //Constructor to the class
    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        //Initializing tab count
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
    }

    //Overriding method getItem
    @Override

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    //Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

while I am trying to do this I was getting an error and error is
"import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter" is attempting 
 to use incompatiable returntype.

Can anyone help me with this?`enter code here`

Comment: Change `import android.app.Fragment;` to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing android.app.Fragment you should use

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

This will solve the issue